# How to prove that $S = \sum_{i=1}^{2^n} \frac{1}{2^n + i} \gt \frac12$ for some natural number $n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

While attempting to prove another statement by induction, I was led to proving that this expression is always greater than $\frac12$. I tried all sorts of manipulation I could come up with to no avail. I hope somebody could help or at least give me some hint to what to do.

Thank you very much!

$S = \sum_{i=1}^{2^n} \frac{1}{2^n + i} \gt \frac12$ for some natural number $n$.

**EDIT**: Oh, I think I've figured it out! This is what I just did:

$\sum_{i=1}^{2^n} (\frac{1}{2^n + i}) - \frac12 = \sum_{i=1}^{2^n} (\frac{1}{2^n + i}) - \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}2^n = \sum_{i=1}^{2^n} (\frac{1}{2^n + i} - \frac{1}{2^{n+1}})$

$= \sum_{i=1}^{2^n} \frac{2^n - i}{2^{n +1}(2^n + i)}$

Since $i \leq 2^n$, the difference must be greater than $0$.

I'm typing this up without much thought on seeing that this seemed to work, so I'm checking it again to make sure it's correct, but even if it is, I wondered if there is a better way!

Comment: If you add your own attempt, it's easier to help you. Did you try proving the statement with induction?

Comment: @Keine_Maschine Hi, I just had some update! Please review my original post. I was proving a different statement by induction, but during the inductive step, it became clear that I must prove that the statement posted above is true. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: When n=1, this is 1/3+1/4=7/12.  Right?

Comment: @T.J.Gaffney Yes!

Comment: Being nitpicky, because you want strict inequality, you should also say "the difference must be **strictly** greater than 0".

Comment: @CalvinLin Thank you very much!

Comment: i want to see an induction proof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly different take:

$\frac{1}{2^n} > \frac{1}{2^n+i}$ for any $i \geq 1$.

Thus the strictly smallest term in each summation is the final term, $\frac{1}{2^n+2^n}=\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$.

Since you have $2^n$ terms, your sum is strictly $> 2^n\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Oh wow I like your approach much better than mine! Thank you very much!

Comment: i want to see an induction proof